# How can I create a calendar event based on a column from other list?

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-foundation, calendar

I've created a list that the user can add an item and insert some infos about a customer. On that list there is a column that is called "Next visit" formatted as date, I would like to know if it is possible to create a Calendar that reflects all the dates based on this other list column.

It would be used by the user o check his calendar based on the "Next Visits" he scheduled.

Thanks!

Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options I can think of:

1. Create a view, that is a calendar, and use that field for the dates. That'll give you a nice calendar view of your info. However, it won't give you much more than that. If you want a real calendar (sync with Outlook) then....
2. Create a basic workflow in SharePoint Designer that creates the event in the calendar. This may be a better option since you'll have some more flexibility, like emailing notifications to users or creating a task to accomplish certain steps before the date. However, for a basic calendar you can just copy the field data to that calendar.

Comment: Considering that my Sharepoint is Foundation, I am unable to sync it with Outlook. The view with the reminder will help a lot. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this by enabling email for the calendar list?  Then, write a workflow that emails that list?  To enable go to List Settings (for the calendar) and under Communications click incoming email settings.  Once configured create a workflow that sends an email to this list based on the next visit date condition.